# Build Semantic UI to public folder with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I am installing Semantic UI with Node.js using the guide at https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html.

So I first install Gulp (`npm install -g gulp`), then Semantic UI (`npm install semantic-ui --save`), and finally I build using

```
cd semantic/
gulp build
```

Now I get a folder `/semantic/` in my project root.

The problem is that I use Express.js, so I have all my views in `/views/` and my static files in `/public/`.

When I build using Gulp, I get the js and css files in `/semantic/dist/`, so I am not able to access them on the client.

What I could do is to use

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'semantic')));
```

and then refer to the css and js files with

```
<link href="/dist/semantic.css">
```

and

```
<script src="/dist/semantic.js">
```

but I would rather have these two files located in `/public/css/` and `/public/js/`, respectively.

What I am doing right now is to just move the two files from `/semantic/dist/` to the two folders in `/public/`, but at https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html, it is recommended to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

but as `/semantic/` is not added as a static folder to Express.js, I am not able to access this folder from the client.

My `semantic.json` file looks like

```
{
  "base": "semantic/",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "dist/",
      "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
      "compressed": "dist/components/",
      "themes": "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "dist/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": true,
  "rtl": false,
  "version": "2.2.9"
}
```

Would it be possible to say that the js files should go to `/public/js/` and the css files to `/public/css/` in this config file?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Curious.